# How do we find the length (depth) of the game tic-tac-toe in adversarial search?

Tags: game-ai, search, minimax, tic-tac-toe, adversarial-search

When we perform the [tic-tac-toe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tic-tac-toe) game using adversarial search, I know how to make a tree. Is there a way to find the depth of the tree, and which level is the last level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean [minimax search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax) as adversarial, you can take a number of free spaces on the board as an upper bound of the tree depth.

Comment: Re *"a number of free spaces"*: Do you mean *"the number of free spaces"*?